# Is this gerund phrase(asking about renting the spare room)

Tags: grammar

"There was a man here just now **asking about renting the spare room**".
Is this bold part a gerund phrase?

Comment: No: There is nothing noun-like about it.  Traditional grammar analyses it as a present participial clause.

Comment: @BillJ It needs comma between "a man here just now and asking about"? Because it is not come immediately after noun it modify "a man"

Comment: You can argue about whether it modifies "a man" or the whole main clause. English allows that kind of ambiguity.

Comment: @user462798 I disagree, but if you feel there should be a comma why didn't you insert one when you typed your question?

Comment: @BillJ. I thought full phrase (asking about renting the spare room) working as a gerund phrase. So I didn't insert a comma.

Comment: @user462798 Gerund clauses are not always separated by commas. In your example, the present participial clause "asking about renting the spare room" modifies "man". No comma is required.

Answer (score 1):

> *There was a **man** here just now* [***asking about renting the spare room***].

No: Traditional grammar analyses it as a present participial clause. There is nothing noun-like about its form or function, so it cannot be a gerund clause.

The participial clause, bracketed, is in postposed position, at the end of the clause containing the noun it modifies.

This typically occurs when the informational content of the modifying clause is greater then that of the material that would follow it in the matrix clause if it occupied the default position following the noun. Compare the somewhat awkward sounding basic (non-extraposed) version:

> *There was a man asking about renting the spare room here just now.*